# .Net Core 7, integration with Google API getting error " 'GetFallbackPolicyAsync' in type 'Google.Apis.Auth.AspNetCore.GoogleScopedPolicyProvider'

Tags: c#, .net

We are trying to integrate Google API: Google Drive in our .Net Core (7) Application. Following [document](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth#web-applications-asp.net-core-3) but while executing the code getting following error.

> Method 'GetFallbackPolicyAsync' in type 'Google.Apis.Auth.AspNetCore.GoogleScopedPolicyProvider' from assembly 'Google.Apis.Auth.AspNetCore'.

We have taken the latest versions of libraries. But still showing `GetFallbackPolicyAsync` definition is missing in `Google.Apis.Auth.AspNetCore`.

Unable to get the proper solution to integrate the Google Drive API in .Net Core application.
How to fix this issue?

Our scenario is, if user try to access Google Drive and he is not authenticated with Google it should redirect to Google login page and after login he should be able to access the Google Drive.
We tried to use [this](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Google#versions-body-tab) for the Auth, but getting same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have the exact same problem as you, using ASP.NET Core 7.0 and Google Calendars API.

So I tried to switch to **Google.Apis.Auth.AspNetCore3** instead of **Google.Apis.Auth.AspNetCore**.

It seems to work now (without the need for 'GetFallbackPolicyAsync' implementation), and I haven't seen any problem for the moment.

Could you give it a try ?